# Formatting output from CLI Program

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I'm building a tool to monitor the output of a tool I'm using on the command line.  The output isn't formatted very friendly and I'm having difficulty getting it into a usable format.  I've tried exploding the lines with PHP_EOL and then exploding tabs, but it appears to be spaces used and not tabs so then separating the different parts is difficult.  An example of the raw output I'm working with is below.

```
    ID   Done       Have  ETA           Up    Down  Ratio  Status       Name
 5   100%   13.43 GB  Done         0.0     0.0    0.0  Seeding      File 1
 9   100%    1.94 GB  Done         0.0     0.0    0.0  Idle         File 2 - Prequel to File 3
Sum:            15.37 GB               0.0     0.0
```

Has anybody got any suggestions?  Maybe there's a PHP function I'm missing, or there's something I can add to the CLI command to control the format?

Thanks

Comment: "there's something I can add to the CLI command to control the format", can you tell us the CLI command?

Comment: Command is "transmission-remote -l"

Comment: Show us how you are outputting stuff then we can see if there is a better way

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean https://linux.die.net/man/1/transmission-remote. If yes, I did not find any switch to the command that will make output better.

But for output itself, I would not call it all that bad. I do not believe there is specific command but output it pretty distinct fortunately.

This is the scheme I will use to code it:

The columns are fixed: `ID   Done       Have  ETA           Up    Down  Ratio  Status       Name`

First - either int or "sum:" followed by space

Done: Number followed by %

Have: Float followed by KB\MB\GB

ETA: either "Done" or perhaps Days:hour:min:sec format

Up\down\ratio: float

Status: Seeding\idle...

File: remaining

Now, if you wanted to convert this to regex:

So you have to patterns:

1. For individual download:

`(\d+)[ \t]+([\d.]+%[ \t])[ \t]+([\d.]+[ ](GB|MB|KB))[ \t]+(\w+)[ \t]+([\d.]+)[ \t]+([\d.]+)[ \t]+([\d.]+)[ \t]+(\w+)[ \t]+(.*)`

2. If this does not match:

`(sum:)[ \t]+([\d.]+[ ](GB|MB|KB))[ \t]+([\d.]+)[ \t]+([\d.]+)`

You can or them or merge them.
Once they match, all you have to do really is to extract groups.